# What "unsinning weaknesses" are meant by Milton in chapter V of "The Doctrine & Discipline of Divorce"?

Tags: meaning, john-milton, doctrine-and-discipline-of-divorce

In [book one](https://milton.host.dartmouth.edu/reading_room/ddd/book_1/text.shtml), chapter V, of *The Doctrine & Discipline of Divorce*, it is written:

> Thirdly, Yet it is next to be fear'd, if he must be still bound without reason by a deafe rigor, that when he perceives the just expectance of his mind defeated, he will begin even against Law to cast about where he may find his satisfaction more compleat, unlesse he be a thing heroically vertuous, and that are not the common lump of men for whom chiefly the Laws ought to be made, though not to their sins, yet to their **unsinning weaknesses**, it being above their strength to endure the lonely estate, which while they shun'd, they are fal'n into.

What *[unsinning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsinning) weaknesses* are meant here? For whom the laws ought to be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a very difficult sentence to parse. Milton is enumerating the various reasons why a Christian law permitting divorce is necessary. He says that if a man is married to an uncongenial partner, and then discovers that he is bound by an unjustifiable ("without reason") law of stubborn strictness ("deaf rigor") to stay married to that person, then that man's reasonable expectations ("just expectance") of any kind of marital bliss are quashed. Then unless that man is unusually, even "heroically", virtuous, he will begin considering illegal and immoral ("against Law") ways of fulfilling those needs that his marriage doesn't meet.

Milton says that most people ("the common lump of men") are however not "that", i.e., they are not heroically virtuous. To directly answer the question you explicitly ask in your last sentence: Milton says that **"Laws ought to be made" for those who are not heroically virtuous**, but not to address their *sins*; rather, to address their *unsinning weakness*. Instead of having only laws that address sins (e.g., the law forbidding adultery), the state should also have laws that help people who are not sinful, but weak—such as those who might be tempted to adultery because they cannot bear the loneliness of an uncongenial married life.

To put all of the above more clearly: A married man who is estranged from his wife has shunned the lonely estate of being single, yet has fallen into that estate. This is unendurable, yet he can find no relief, as there is no law that allows divorce. Laws, such as those against adultery, are made about sins; they are not made to help such a man, who is as yet unsinning. This man, so far sinless, might still prove too weak to bear his lonely plight. He might in fact be tempted to go against the law and to sin by committing adultery. So the focus of the Law needs to be different. Rather than focusing on sinners, it should focus on those who have not yet sinned, but are weak and so might end up sinning. In order to help the unsinning weakness of such men, it is necessary to legalize divorce.

The slippages in Milton's rhetoric between the law as a moral/religious edict and as a civil matter, or between marriage as the union of souls and as a legal way to avoid adultery, are fascinating. And the temptation to read this passage biographically or psychoanalytically is great. But you asked only for a paraphrase, so I'll do us both a favor and stop right here.